# In CNN, do we have learn kernel values at every convolution layer?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm new to machine learning and one of the things I don't understand about CNN is whether we have to learn the kernel values at every convolutional layer, or just learn a single set of kernel values and use it at every convolution layer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer by @Shehryar Malik is correct (+1), but it sounds a bit confusing, especially for people new to convolutional neural networks.

**In the usual CNN scenario, each layer has its own set of convolution kernels that has to be learned**. This can be easily seen in the following (famous) image:

[image]

The left block shows learned kernels in the first layer. The central and right block show kernels learned in deeper layers<sup>1</sup>. This is very important feature of convolutional neural networks: At different layers the network learns to detect stuff at different levels of abstraction. **Therefore the kernels are different.**

In theory, nothing prevents you from using the same kernels at each layer. In fact, that thing is called [recurrent convolutional neural network](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Recurrent-convolutional-neural-network-for-object-Liang-Hu/3faabe9428e76ac96af6d81a34cfe0a823e947af).

---

<sup>1</sup> More precisely, they show to what kind of image features these kernels respond to, since visualizing kernel with shape 3$\times$3$\times$256 is not very easy/intuitive/useful.

Comment: Interesting, but speaking of confusion, recurrent convolutional network seems a bit of an unfortunate name if I understand it correctly: Is RCNN it different from an RNN with convolutional layers?

Comment: RCNN is indeed unfortunate, as it is also established as an acronym for [networks for object detection](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2524). But to answer your question, I think the difference is if you apply the same conv. filter repeatedly on the same data (recurrent convnet) or if you pass the data through some conv. layers and then apply standard RNN (as LSTM units), so the recurrence actually does not involve convolutions. Both is possible I think, even though I am no expert on recurrent nets.

Comment: Great answer! How can I define my own kernels?

Comment: Are these direct renderings of the filters, or are they renderings of images in pixel space that yield max activation? I'm guessing it's the former--the latter have a much more psychedelic look--am I correct in guessing that this is a direct render of the filters?

Comment: The first layer (left image) is a direct render of the filters, the rest are some sort of activation maximizers. Since the higher layer filters are not in 3 channels (RGB), they cannot be directly visualized.

Answer (score 4):

That is entirely up to you. You can define only one set of kernel values and use it for all your layers or instead you could define a separate set of kernel values for each layer. Of course, it would be more prudent to define different sets of kernel values for each layer. This is because the kernel's job is to extract specific information from an input image. Different sets of kernel values at each layer will allow the network greater flexibility in deciding the best features to extract at each layer.

Comment: If you define one kernel for each layer, you will still have to tie the weights to accomplish what @thegoodguy asked.

Comment: @FransRodenburg what do you mean by 'tie the weights'? For a CNN, the 'kernel' is the 'weight matrix' and that is essentially what the network is trying to learn.

Comment: Even if you have the same kernel dimensions for each convolutional layer, you will still learn different weights. The OP asked whether the *values* are the same, which is only the case if you force them to be (i.e. tie the weights).

Comment: So the conclusion is ,I have to learn kernel values for each convolution layer.

Comment: @FransRodenburg when I said kernel I meant a set of kernel _values_ (a kernel is after all only a weight matrix, and two different weight matrices might have the same dimensions). Nevertheless, I am editing my answer to make this more apparent.

Comment: @thegoodguy Yes.

Comment: How can I define my own kernels?